# Creating a Browse panel ( JPanel) for eCommerce items and adding them to a cart (another JPanel)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jbutton

I am creating this movie rental app and I have to have a panel where you can see available movies either all of them or filter them through categories or search them by name. 
Then the user has to be able to add them into their cart to check them out.
Now, for the first step, I don't know what component to use to make these actions possible. I thought of using one button(add button), one label(title) and one image(poster of the movie) and a textArea (description) for each movie but then I dont know how to make them searchable or filter them. 
Now my guess is, there should be some component that could provide some of these properties already or there should be another combination of the components to achieve this task, but again I cannot think of anything else.

Comment: For the 'browse panel' use a `JTable`. It can support text, numbers, icons etc. It can also perform filtering or sorting of the rows of the table.

Comment: [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: See a relevant [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/TabbableCurrencyTable.htm)